# Complex numbers and absolute values

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

If i have equation:

\begin{align}
P = \left|\psi\right|^2
\end{align}

where $P$ is a probability and we know there is no negative probability. This means $P$ must belong to $\mathbb{R}$. If i want to calculate $|\psi|$ i can do it simply by sq. rt. the equation:

\begin{align}
\left|\psi\right| = \sqrt{P}
\end{align}

Is $\left|\psi\right|$ a real number? What about $\psi$ by itself? Please explain.

Comment: You cannot get $\psi$ from $P$, only its magnitude can be found. Even with real numbers you cannot find a unique $x$ from $x^2=9$, you only get the absolute value $|x|=3$. The phase angle of $\psi$ cannot be recovered from the given equation.

Comment: The modulus $|z|$ is always a *positive real number*, and its square will also be nonnegative.

Comment: But there is a possibility that $\psi$ is complex?

Comment: Yes, that is a possibility.

Comment: But it could allso be real right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The absolute value of a complex number (sometimes called its *modulus*) is real by construction. If $\psi=\alpha+i\beta$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ real, then $|\psi|=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$.

Comment: This means $\left|\psi\right|$ is always real and $\psi$ complex? Can you please edit your anwser and show me how you got equation $\left|\psi\right|=\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}$.

Comment: That equation is the *definition* of the absolute value. So I can't show you how I “got” it, except perhaps by pointing to a thousand textbooks that all define it that way. So yes, that means $|\psi|$ is real. The square root is the usual square root as applied to a positive real numbers.

Comment: I'm nitpicking, I know, but it's not only real, it's even guaranteed to be $\geq 0$.

Comment: @fgp: The modulus is a wonderful beast indeed!

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen It's nothing compared to the phase! Oh, the pure joy of recklessly adding $2\pi$ and watching *nothing* change... always shuddering at bit at the dreaded possibility that I, one day, just *might* happen to try this on a riemannian manifold....